# Disable Buttons during AsyncTask

Tags: android, button, android-asynctask

I programmed an quiz-app and if I touch one of the answers in an AsyncTask if the answer is correct I set the color to green or if it is false to red.

But now during the time the AsyncTask runs I can press other buttons like the "change question" button or on another one of the answers. This is then done after the AsyncTask has finished it's work. So the next question is loaded and it automatically answers the next question or uses one of the jokers what ever.

I tried to setEnabled(false) the Buttons but they are still bugging.

How do I prevent this?

```
private void disableOrDisableButtons(boolean boo) {
        buttonAnswer1.setEnabled(boo);
        buttonAnswer2.setEnabled(boo);
        buttonAnswer3.setEnabled(boo);
        buttonAnswer4.setEnabled(boo);
    }
```

and here I start the AsyncTask

```
disableOrDisableButtons(false);
new PrepareAdapter().execute(null, null, null);
```

in my AsyncTask

```
@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            disableOrDisableButtons(false);
            if (correctAnswerAtButton != buttonClicked) {
                switch (buttonClicked) {
                case 1:
                    buttonAnswer1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    buttonAnswer2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    buttonAnswer3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    buttonAnswer4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                }
                if (buttonClicked != 0) { // 0.. if second chance joker used
                    wrongAnswer = true;
                }
            }
            switch (correctAnswerAtButton) {
            case 1:
                buttonAnswer1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                return;
            case 2:
                buttonAnswer2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                return;
            case 3:
                buttonAnswer3.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                return;
            case 4:
                buttonAnswer4.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Unless it is some kind of training exercise, stop using threads. It is not the sort of application that needs to be multi-threaded at all, and it is just creating additional problems for you.

Comment: so what should i do then? thank you for your answer

Comment: Just do everything in the main UI thread. I imagine that the processing involved is fairly trivial, so there is no need to keep the UI thread open.

Comment: i used AsyncTask because without it i couldn't find a way to chance the color of the button text and with the AsyncTask it's possible to pause the app to show the user the correct answer.

in the main UI thread i think it's impossible to change the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way i use it now to lock my screen during the AsyncTask. For me it is perfect now. Hope it can help u.

```
private class PrepareAdapter extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>
            implements DialogInterface.OnCancelListener {
        private Dialog dialog = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // To disable the whole screen --> setCancelable(false);
            dialog = new Dialog(WerWeissWasQuizActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //do other stuff...
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cancel(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I you want to disable the whole interface while the AsyncTask runs, you can use code such as the following to display a dialog:

```
public abstract class BaseAsyncTask<Param, Result> extends AsyncTask<Param, Void, Result> implements DialogInterface.OnCancelListener {
    private static final String TAG = "BaseAsyncTask";
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    protected Context ctx = null;
    protected Exception exception = null;

    public BaseAsyncTask(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, WLConstants.MSG_TITLE_LOADING_DIALOG, WLConstants.MSG_LOADING_DIALOG, true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setOnCancelListener(this);
        if (ctx instanceof WozzonActivity) {
            ((WozzonActivity) ctx).setCurrentDialog(dialog);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Result doInBackground(Param... parameters) {
        try {
            return inBackground(parameters);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            exception = ex;
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getClass().getName(), ex);
            return null;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
        try {
            dialog.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }// TODO:
        if (result == null) {
            onException(exception);
        } else {
            onResult(result);
        }
    }

    protected void onException(Exception ex) {
        if (ex != null && ex instanceof WozzonException) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, WLConstants._ERROR_MSG, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    public abstract void onResult(Result result);
    public abstract Result inBackground(Param... parameters) throws Exception;

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface theDialog) {
        cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a matter of preference I guess... I prefer to display the "Please wait" dialog shown above just so I don't disable each and every individual interface item. That will increase your overall code complexity. Also the user knows exactly what's going on if he sees something like that. But some users will not like it I guess...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the onPreExecute() method of the ASyncTask().

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to threads at all. Try setTextColor(#ff0000) and settextColor(#00ff00), instead of settextColor(Color.RED) and setTextColor(Color.GREEN).